# Javascript: Get input and set it to Array name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a collection of arrays in my script, as follows

```
var data0 = [100,10,15,20];
var data1 = [5,100,15,20];
var data2 = [5,10,100,20];
var data3 = [5,10,15,100];
```

I am getting an input through a click event, which will be the index of the click.

```
function clickEvent(i) {
var dataNum = "data" + i;
        render2(i); 
    }
```

I want to set a new var equal to the array at the index which we got as an input. In java, this would have worked. But here, I think dataNum is a string and not an array. Anyway I can set dataNum to array?

For example, when my click event returns index 0, I want dataNum to be set to array data0

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be easier if you used one array to hold the data:

```
var data = [
    [100, 10, 15, 20],
    [5, 100, 15, 20],
    [5, 10, 100, 20],
    [5, 10, 15, 100]
];
```

then you can access the array index as you would any other array:

```
function clickEvent(i) {
    var dataNum = data[i];
    render2(i); 
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/dgTw4/)

Comment: That makes much more sense than what I was trying to do. #facepalm Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval("data" + i) to evaluate the code in the string and get the array from it.

But I would use the other answer of holding it as an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [two-dimensional](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html) arrays to deal with it.